# set value of input tag to another value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have an HTML input tag and I want to change the value of it when clicking on a button, all before submitting the whole form.

I am trying to use getElementById(idOfInput).value = "value I want to set it to", but that doesn't seem to work.

Check out the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dchaddock/83NZu/1/

```
<input id="resetTesting" value="Testing" />
<button type="button" onclck="resetInput();">Testing</button>

function resetInput() {
    document.getElementById("resetTesting").value = "I'm reset!";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `onclck` attribute of your button a typo on this posting, or does it exist in your page? If the latter, that's at least part of your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You misspelled `onclick`:

```
<button type="button" onclck="resetInput();">Testing</button>
                         ^
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/83NZu/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Here is jsFiddle Link

http://jsfiddle.net/83NZu/3/

```
<input id="resetTesting" value="Testing" />
<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" >Testing</button>

    $(function(){
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            $("#resetTesting").val('test'); // Set the Value
            alert($("#resetTesting").val()); // Get the Value
        })
    })
```

Comment: OP never said anything about using jQuery.

Comment: @user2063626, where do you ever see the OP mention jQuery being available or in use (or something he would even recognize)?

Comment: Infact there is not even a jQuery tag assigned to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't defined when your javascript compiler hits your onclick="resetInput();".
Place the script before the html and you should be good to go.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetInput() {

    document.getElementById("resetTesting").value = "I'm reset!";
}
</script>
<input id="resetTesting" value="Testing" />
<button type="button" onClick="resetInput();">Testing</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83NZu/6/

also... as everyone else mentioned... its onclick ;)

```
edit
```

This is incorrect.  The problem with the original jsfiddle was both the typo and the setting of onLoad vs no-wrap (head) fwiw

Comment: That is not the problem. An inline event handler is the same as the body of a function. The value of `onclick` is not run until click, at which point `resetInput` has been defined (even if you clicked during the split second it wasn't defined, subsequent clicks would be fine). Your example works because you corrected the real issue of the typo'd attribute.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Thanks for the lesson.  The problem with the original post jsfiddle was that they had framework setting as onLoad... not sure why that broke the jsfiddle, fwiw

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the default option "onload" and the error spell `onclck`:

The "onLoad" option means:wrap the code so it will run in onLoad window event

HTML code:

```
<input id="resetTesting" value="Testing" />
<button id="btn" type="button">Testing</button>
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("resetTesting").value="I'm reset";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83NZu/8/

or choose the option"no wrap(head)",it means:do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in `<head>` section

http://jsfiddle.net/83NZu/7/